# Creating a PDF from a QT application

Tags: python, qt, pdf-generation, pyqt4

I'm working on an app that will display an image and some text. But I want to export the whole QT interface as a PDF (By pressing on a button on the UI itself). All the text and all the images just as it appears on the UI.

Now if that isn't possible, maybe I can some how automatically create a jpg, save it and then somehow, using reportlab, to convert the jpg to a PDF.

I have no idea where to start. Can any one please give me an example or even just a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QPixmap.grabWidget` to capture you main window widget and `QPrinter` to produce a pdf file. A `QPainter` is needed to draw the pixmap to the printer.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work, I got the grabWidget to work, now just to convert to pdf or print. Here is a short part I added to my code to save as image. Thanks again.                                             im = QPixmap.grabWidget(self); im.save('C:/test.png')